# Need help trying to replicate Microsoft steps in WinDBG

Tags: asp.net, debugging, windbg

We sent this dump to MS and they sent us back these results. I am trying to replicate this so that we can find out why the web app crashed on a different server. My comments start with @@@. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
0:025> !critlist @@@ *This command is no longer available so I used !locks*
CritSec at 786dd8e0.  Owned by thread 25.
```

thread 25 is holding the critical section (or lacking) and below are the threads are waiting on it.

Impact of this lock @@@ *I can reproduce this in Debug Diag Tool*

70.42% of threads blocked

(Threads 15 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 134 135 138)

-- checking the call stack:

```
:025> kL

ChildEBP RetAddr  

0285fcc4 7c827b69 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet

0285fcc8 77e6202c ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc

0285fd70 77e62fbe kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x11a

0285fd8c 79f8e39a kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18

0285fdac 79f8e48c mscorwks!SVR::WaitForFinalizerEvent+0x77

0285fdc0 79e9caff mscorwks!SVR::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadWorker+0x49

0285fdd4 79e9ca9b mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+0x4f

0285fe68 79e9c9c1 mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+0xb1

0285fea4 79f20508 mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+0x6d

0285fecc 79f20519 mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase_NoADTransition+0x32

0285fedc 79f220eb mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase::FinalizerBase+0xd

0285ff14 79f0e255 mscorwks!SVR::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadStart+0xbb

0285ffb8 77e6482f mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x49

0285ffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x34
```

-- rebuild the stack: @@@I am unable to find out how to rebuild the stack to produce the results below. I need to know which DLL is causing the lock. In this example secSSo.dll. Once i find out I can use command lmvm to find the owner of the thread.

```
0285dc00  00000000

0285dc04  000b7a80

0285dc08  23000003*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols 

for secSSO.dll - 

 secSSO!SSOStartLogin+0x8d6f4

0285dc0c  0285dc74

0:025> lmvm secSSO
start    end        module name
22f70000 23036000   secSSO     (export symbols)       secSSO.dll

    Loaded symbol image file: secSSO.dll

    Image path: C:\Program Files\Business Objects\Common\2.8\bin\secSSO.dll

    Image name: secSSO.dll

    Timestamp:        Sun Oct 14 01:39:17 2007 (4711AB85)

    CheckSum:         000C83D4

    ImageSize:        000C6000

    File version:     10.5.0.1943

    Product version:  10.5.0.1943

    File flags:       8 (Mask 3F) Private

    File OS:          4 Unknown Win32

    File type:        1.0 App

    File date:        00000000.00000000

    Translations:     0409.04b0

    CompanyName:      Business Objects

    ProductName:      Crystal Enterprise

    InternalName:     Crystal Enterprise

    OriginalFilename: Crystal Enterprise

    ProductVersion:   10.5.0.1943

    FileVersion:      10.5.0.1943

    FileDescription:  Crystal Enterprise

    LegalCopyright:   Copyright (C)1995-2007 Business Objects

    LegalTrademarks:  Crystal Enterprise (tm) is a trademark of Business Objects
```

-- so either thread 25 already leaked the Criticalsection or doing nothing, and rest of the threads are just waiting on it.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to rebuild the stack as mention above from Microsoft to identified the owner of the locked thread.

Comment: You may use `!critlist` command if you load `.load sos\sieextpub.dll`. The [~s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565430(v=vs.85).aspx) command sets or displays the current thread number.

Comment: Did you have AppVerifier enabled on the process when you captured the dump? Otherwise I cannot see how they can extract initialization call stack.

Comment: Do anyone knows how they rebuild the stack to get this result?
0285dc08  23000003*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols 

for secSSO.dll -

Comment: Thanks. That commands gives me this:
0:025> ~25s; kL
eax=79e720e0 ebx=0285fd14 ecx=000f16f0 edx=0000004b esi=0285fd18 edi=7ffd7000

Comment: eip=7c82845c esp=0285fcc8 ebp=0285fd70 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet:
7c82845c c3              ret
ChildEBP RetAddr  
0285fcc4 7c827b69 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
0285fcc8 77e6202c ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
0285fd70 77e62fbe kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x11a
0285fd8c 79f8e39a kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18
0285fdac 79f8e48c mscorwks!SVR::WaitForFinalizerEvent+0x77

Comment: 0285fdc0 79e9caff mscorwks!SVR::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadWorker+0x49
0285fdd4 79e9ca9b mscorwks!Thread::DoADCallBack+0x32a
0285fe68 79e9c9c1 mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0xe3
0285fea4 79f20508 mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0x30a
0285fecc 79f20519 mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase_NoADTransition+0x32
0285fedc 79f220eb mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase::FinalizerBase+0xd
0285ff14 79f0e255 mscorwks!SVR::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadStart+0xbb
0285ffb8 77e6482f mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x49
0285ffec 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x34

Comment: There is no reasonable explanation for the transition to the `0285dc08  23000003 secSSO!SSOStartLogin+0x8d6f4`

Comment: Debug Diag Tool points to thread 25
Detected possible blocking or leaked critical section at mfc90!_afxResourceLock+168 owned by thread 25

Comment: Windbg--

0:000> !locks

CritSec mfc90!_afxResourceLock+168 at 786dd8e0
WaiterWoken        No
LockCount          100
RecursionCount     1
OwningThread       1544
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    64
*** Locked


0:025> !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x1544 (25)
Failed to start stack walk: 80004005

Comment: where I am getting at is how do I find who owns the thread 25 or thread id: 0x1544

Comment: This error 80004005 means that a) you are loading the wrong version of `sos.dll`, i.e. in this case I loaded the 2.0 version in a 1.1 dump, or b) it can't find the proper version of `mscordacwks.dll`.  If it is option b, try turning on `!sym noisy`  and run `.cordll -ve -u -l`.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/05/13/failed-to-start-stack-walk-80004005-following-frames-may-be-wrong-and-other-errors-you-may-see-in-windbg.aspx